# LINQ to SQL: DataContext changes are not reflected unless SubmitChanges is called

Tags: .net, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a a User class and related UserRequest, so VS designer created User.UserRequests for me.

Occasionally I execute a task to remove inactive UserRequests as follows:

```
Dim requests = From req In db.UserRequests Where req.LastActivity < DateTime.Now.Subtract(New TimeSpan(0, 0, KeepRequestInterval)) Select req 


For Each req In requests 

    db.UserRequests.DeleteOnSubmit(req )
Next
```

When I access the User.UserRequests, removed Requests are still there, unless I call db.SubmitChanges() after removing them, before accessing User.UserRequests.

Is there any way to force removal of deleted Requests from User.UserRequests without an additional call to SubmitChanges()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is by design. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399378.aspx

> Regardless of how many changes you make to your objects, changes are
>   made only to in-memory replicas. You have made no changes to the
>   actual data in the database. Your changes are not transmitted to the
>   server until you explicitly call SubmitChanges on the DataContext.

Only after Submitchanges will your deletes be removed.

Comment: I agree, the only way to actually change the database is through SubmitChanges().  Until then, the transactions are in a Queue which is not enacted if SubmitChanges() is never called.

Comment: How about removing them manually from the collection? Is that a good practice?

Comment: eh, what is the underlying goal you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 1):

You could check each entry in User.UserRequests against the results of db.GetChangeSet().  GetChangeSet returns 3 collections(Deletes, Inserts, Updates) of what has been changed since the last submit.

```
ChangeSet cs = db.GetChangeSet();
```

More info here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.getchangeset.aspx